# Foundation 5 JS not working in Rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation-5

I am trying to get Foundation 5 javascript components (any of them) to work in a Rails 4.2.0 app, but nothing I have tried seems to work. I am using the `foundation-rails` gem, and have followed the [documented steps to install it](https://github.com/zurb/foundation-rails#manual-installation).

To test that Foundation JS works, I've inserted the basic HTML for a tooltip, explained [here](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/tooltips.html), to show a tooltip link:

```
<span data-tooltip aria-haspopup="true" class="has-tip" title="Tooltips are awesome, you should totally use them!">extended information</span>
```

On the page, the tooltip link is styled correctly, however, the tooltip function itself does not work and falls back to the system alt text, as shown below:

[image: tooltip pic]

My first guess was that there is something wrong with the way I included the Foundation JS files, However, I have double-checked the source for pages in my app, and they all seem to be there:

[image: foundation JS includes]

I have also verified that `$(document).foundation()` is being included in the Rails app's application.js:

[image: application.js]

The JS components of Foundation still don't function, even if I place `$(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });` in a script tag right before the element that it affects.

How can I debug this? Is there something I can run in the JS console to figure out what is going on?

Comment: Are you including `modernizr`? `javascript_include_tag "vendor/modernizr"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I was able to fix this right after I applied the bounty! It seems the issue was somehow related to how Rails caches assets in development environments ([this article](http://www.tkalin.com/blog_posts/rails-4-disable-assets-caching-for-development-test-environments/) says a little bit about it).

Basically, I had recently upgraded Foundation 4 to Foundation 5, and I didn't realize it but the SCSS assets being served were still Foundation 4's assets, not those of Foundation 5. I accidentally figured this out when I restarted my computer and all of a sudden tooltips worked.

If anyone else has this issue, I would try wiping rails cache by running the command `rake tmp:clear` and seeing if that fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you can add

```
config.serve_static_files = true
```

in your development.rb config file and make sure you don't precompile, this makes rails load the assets from the original location every time, which reflects changes that are made instantly.

Comment: This is incorrect - `serve_static_assets` is deprecated, the correct setting is `serve_static_files`.